# How to force MSVS 2010 to use qt debug libraries in a C++ project?

Tags: qt, debugging, build, linker

I have a C++ project that uses QT libraries. The project is in MSVS 2010.
When I try to build the project in "Debug mode" I get this error:

```
qtmain.lib(qtmain_win.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in audiomixerboard.obj
```

The correct "qtmain" library with debug info is called "qtmaind.lib", but for some reason in my project it wants to use "qtmain.lib".

My question is: how to force the MSVS 2010 linker to use qt libraries with debug information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply specify qtmaind.lib in the properties->linker->input tab, addition dependancies field